# Why isnt the acceleration vector always orthogonal to the velocity vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We know that $v=r'$ and acceleration $a=v' = r''$. Following the rule that if the vector v has a magnitude, then $\langle v, v'\rangle =0$ thus $v$ and $v'$ should be orthogonal. But when i was selfstudying, i got curious and tried to see if this applied.

Lets take an example for $r(t)=(t,t^2,t^3),
v(t)=r'(t)=(1,2t,3t^2),
a(t)=v'(t)=(0,2,3t)$

Lets say we plug in for $t =2$:
$$r(t)=(2,4,8),
v(t)=(1,4,12),
a(t)=(0,2,6)$$

Put it on a graph
[image]
You clearly can see that the vectors are not orthogonal to each other
You can even dot product each of the vectors together and you will not get 0. Is the rule wrong? does it not apply to this case?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your equations. Note that there is no rule that says that $v\cdot v'=0$. You can have an even simpler case, an object falling vertically down. The velocity and acceleration are in the same direction

Comment: This rule is most generally only seen with circular motion. There is no requirement for them to always be orthogonal all of the time.

Comment: @bio this applies more generally to all constant speed motion (but not all motion in general)

Comment: Note that if $z'(t)=3t^2$, then $z''(t)\neq3t$ except for $t=0$

Comment: You can even restrict yourself to a movement in the plane according to the parabola $t\mapsto (t,t^2)$. It's easier to draw.

Comment: $\vec a=v'\vec T+\kappa v^2 \vec N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule applies to constant speed.
Acceleration can be broken into the component $$\vec{a_T}={\vec v'\cdot \vec v\over |\vec v|^2}\vec v$$ tangent to velocity and the component  $\vec {a_N}=\vec v'-\vec{a_T}$ orthogonal to velocity.

The change in speed can be written as
$$|\vec v|' = \left(\sqrt{v\cdot v}\right)' = {v\cdot v'\over\sqrt{v\cdot v}}=|\vec{a_T}|,$$

and this is zero iff $v\cdot v'= 0,$ as you've observed.

As bio said, the place you're going to see this most commonly is circular motion (and, in fact, this looks locally like circular motion), but there are other kinds of constant-speed motion.

Comment: Note that your formula for $\vec a_T$ is incorrect. Dimensionally is $m^2/s^3$ instead of $m/s^2$ (you need to divide by the magnitude of $\vec v$. And a dot product of two vectors is a scalar (so it would be just the magnitude of $\vec a_T$. $$\vec a_T=\frac{\vec v'\cdot\vec v}{|\vec v|^2}\vec v$$